# Replace text of a class name but within a particular id

Tags: javascript

I have the following html:

```
<h2 id="program-selector-modal_heading">
  <span class="modal-heading-before-text"></span>
  <span>Start your application to </span>
  <span class="modal-heading-after-text"></span>
</h2>
```

and I'm trying to update the text shown in the class `modal-heading-text-after` for this particular id heading:

```
const programSelectorModalHeadingOuter = document.getElementById("program-selector-modal_heading");
programSelectorModalHeadingOuter.getElementsByClassName("modal-heading-after-text").innerHTML = "test";
```

But it's not working. Any ideas? My environment setup is strange and I can't see errors.

Comment: try to use document.querySelector

document.querySelector('#program-selector-modal_heading .modal-heading-after-text').innerHTML = "test"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is that `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of matches.

So when you try and set the `text` attribute you're actually setting it against the matching *set* of HTML elements - not a HTML element within that array.

There may only be 1 element in that set, but it will always return an array, not a single element.

If you change the second line to address the `[0]` index element within that array it should work.

The final code for your JS would look like this:

```
const programSelectorModalHeadingOuter = document.getElementById("program-selector-modal_heading");
programSelectorModalHeadingOuter.getElementsByClassName("modal-heading-after-text")[0].innerHTML = "test";
```

That should then work.